# ¿Como seria posible realizar la siguente consulta?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `ofertas` WHERE date LIKE '2016-12-20%' BETWEEN LIKE '2017-01-16%'
```

Deseo consultar un rango de fechas pero la columna `date` se encuentra declarada con el predeterminado `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  por lo que al realizar la consulta con la clausula `BETWEEN` tendría que ingresar también la hora de registro´.

¿Será posible realizar esta consulta con solo la fecha y no la hora, sin tener que modificar la estructura de la tabla debido a que la hora la uso en otros apartados del sistema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias usar una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT * FROM ofertas WHERE date >= '2016-12-20 00:00:00' AND date <= '2017-01-16 23:59:59'
```

O incluso, podrias usar la funcion *between* de SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM ofertas WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-12-20 00:00:00' AND '2017-01-16 23:59:59'
```

Lo que haces es fijar los valores de hora de manera estatica, lo unico que tendrias que cambiar es la fecha.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) para convertir a `date` el valor de la columna `datetime`.

Así por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM `ofertas` WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2016-12-20' AND '2017-01-16'
```